# Is there a way to convert the Park PCS-12 to PCS-10?

Tags: maintenance

I have the bench mount PCS-12 but am looking to convert it to a floor mount.  I haven't been able to find the base for the PCS-10, only the entire unit.  Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: I think you need to buy the whole PCS-10 unit if you want to convert the bench stand to the portable stand.

Comment: You can always make your own base, of course.  And there are cheaper floor stands available than the PCS-10.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to buy just the floor stand without the clamp unless you chance to buy one at a yard sale or on ebay, you *might* be able to contact Park Tool and ask them if they can send you just the floor stand without the clamp as a replacement part, but I doubt it for that particular stand.

My advice would be to just buy the new stand, [amazon sells them](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B000OZFJS4/ref=s9_simh_gw_p200_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1MJA9892FV97DZRSYTA8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1947489602&pf_rd_i=915398) for $90 less than their listed price. And you can get them for even cheaper than that on [ebay](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Park-Tool-PCS-10-Home-Mechanic-Bicycle-Bike-Repair-Stand-/331258450458?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d208ad21a). Then you can keep you bench mount for spare parts or just leave it where it is and have two stands.

You could try building a floor stand out of chain link fence parts depending on the size of post you need to fit the clamp. The cheapest solution would probably be to buy one post (or *borrow* one from a local school) and a [floor flange](http://fencesupplyinc.com/shop/floor-flange-molded-1-7-8.html), and either bolt it to your garage floor (permanent) or to a **big** piece of thick plywood (which will eventually break). I don't recommend looking at getting piece of plate steel like the PRS Deluxe stands have, because I've looked into it before and the size plate you's want would cost almost as much as a new PCS stand would. If you can get anything free by chance or from a junker/someone you know then that's a bonus.

But like I said, I think you'd be better of just to [buy a new stand](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Park-Tool-PCS-10-Home-Mechanic-Bicycle-Bike-Repair-Stand-/331258450458?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d208ad21a).